# Codeblocks Crash

Tags: code-blocks

I don't have a good experience with codeblocks on Ubuntu. I've tried in 15.10 and 16.04 and it always crashes after a while. I just open a console application, create some .h files and run.
I use it for a c++ university class. I don't do complex stuff.
I reinstalled many times on both 15.10 and 16.04 and it  keeps crashing .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Geany](http://apt://geany) to write, edit, compile and run C++ source code. But if you want to use codeblocks, then please install the latest version of codeblocks 16.01. To install codeblocks 16.01 run this commands in terminal.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Comment: Is there any difference between doing that and downloading from ubuntu software center?

Comment: may be software center not updated latest version of codeblocks.

Comment: My Codeblocks 16.01 is still chrasing randomly.

Answer (score 3):

Try to disable symbol browser of code completion and see if the crushes stop.

Go to:

- Settings
- Editor
- Code Completion (on the left)
- Symbols browser

And check "✔ Disable symbols browser".

I had the same issue and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that Codeblocks on Ubuntu *is* unstable. With Codeblocks 16.01 on Ubuntu 19.04, I see the same issues reported by others — editor freezing, and the application closing suddenly.

In [a message](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,21737.msg147843.html#msg147843) on the Codeblocks forum, a developer responding to the issue says "You've hit some of the nasty bugs I have no idea how to fix", and he refers to an [old discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wx-dev/r_QdyEzoM4I) from the year 2008 on the wxWidgets developer forum about the problem.

It's a bit surprising that there's a long-standing unresolved bug in a cross-platform GUI library as popular as wxWidgets that causes problems like this, but that seems to be the situation. Unfortunate.

Comment: Any Idea on a version that is stable? - I like the symbols browser

Comment: @ Nivatius. I don't know. I only tested the build from Ubuntu's Universe repository before I went in a different direction. I see that there's Debian-packaged binaries on codeblocks.org which I'd assume would work on Ubuntu too. You could try that.

Answer (score -1):

You really don't need CodeBlocks. What you need is `g++` compiler for compiling your code. You should have it installed, if not, then:

```
$ sudo apt install g++
```

For convenience to write code, you can install any text editors such as VS Code (my personal favourite), Atom, Vim, Sublime etc. Just create a new file (say, `start.cpp`) in some location of your computer (say, `/home/<username>/Codes` ) and write some code. Then open your terminal in the same location (so in this case, /home//Codes ). Then type:

```
$ g++ start.cpp -o start.out   # this compiles your code
$ ./start.out                  # this is how you run it
```

If you have some inputs in a file (say, `input.txt` ) and want to write the output in some other file (say, `output.txt`), the command is:

```
$ ./start.out < input.txt > output.txt
```

That is basically the terminal way of cpp. You will probably make mistakes, so I suggest you ask your teacher/someone experienced with terminal. 
I hope you will never bother to install CodeBlocks again in youe life :)